# Django migration involving RenameModel not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have been successfully using `makemigrations` and `migrate` in Django 1.7 for altering, adding and removing fields. Unfortunately, I cannot get it working when trying to rename an intermediate model. I.e. I have two models A and B, linked through a many-to-many field through model X, and I would like to rename X to Y.

Running `manage.py makemigrations` does not detect the rename, instead it deletes X and adds Y. But **that's not the problem**. I replaced Django's autogenerated scripts with:

```
[ migrations.RenameModel(old_name='X',new_name='Y'),
  migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='Y',
        name='a',
        field=models.ForeignKey(related_name=b'Y', to='B'),
    )]
```

This gives me the following error:

`ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field b: X`

So I guess it's struggling with a 'through' relation that contains the old name of the model. I tried adding a migration command to change that relation, updating it to the new name of the intermediate model, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Here's the ticket. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22931

Thanks for showing me django can even detect renames. As the ticket says though, apparently detecting rename / being able to rename is a courtesy not a full blown feature.

Comment: Right. I think what they mean by it being a courtesy is that it is not expected to work if the contents of the model change, which is unsurprising. But it really should work if all you do is to change the name.